# How create new columns according the groups in a table?

Tags: mysql

By using mysql can i create new columns according the groups in a table?i only can get the grouping and group_concat.

```
Before
-------------------------
no  |  item   |   code  |
-------------------------
1   |   aa    |    x    |
2   |   cc    |    c    |
3   |   pfr   |    a    |
4   |   bog   |         |
5   |   aa    |    x    |
6   |   pfr   |    x    |
1   |   aa    |    x    |
6   |   pfr   |    a    |
-------------------------
After group and group_concat
-------------------------
no  |  item   |   code  |
-------------------------
1   |   aa    |   x-2   |
2   |   cc    |   c-1   |
3   |   pfr   |   a-1   |
4   |   bog   |         |
5   |   aa    |   x-1   |
6   |   pfr   | a-1,x-1 |
-------------------------
I want to make like below this. Is it possible?
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
no  | aa_qty | aa_code | cc_qty | cc_code | pfr_qty | pfr_code | bog_qty | bog_code |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   2    |   x-2   |        |         |         |          |         |          |
2   |        |         |   1    |   c-1   |         |          |         |          |
3   |        |         |        |         |    1    |   a-1    |         |          |
4   |        |         |        |         |         |          |    1    |          |
5   |   1    |   x-1   |        |         |         |          |         |          |
6   |        |         |        |         |    2    | a-1,x-1  |         |          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Where do you want to count quantity values from and how?

Comment: The quantity is count by grouping (no and item).Example no=1, item=aa, code =x is appear 2 times so the result will show no=1, aa_qty=2, aa_code=x-2.
Another example no=6, item=pfr, code=a and x so result will show no=6,pfr_qty=2, pfr_code=a-1,x-1

Comment: Not really as you will land up with a variable number of columns for each row. You could produce one row per cell and then format it you script, or you could produce one row per row, with concatenated columns including the empty cells.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the application-level code/presentation layer, assuming you have that. It's much simpler, and much more scalable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`Pivot Table`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) mechanism. `MySQL` does not have direct support on this mechanism. You need to depend on various `if .. else..` or `case .. when ...` statements to build the required result view.

On the sample data given, say in table `item_codes` with `no`, `item`, and `code` as columns, you can try following example.

```
select no,
    case item when 'aa' then cnt else '' end as aa_qty,
    case item when 'aa' then code else '' end as aa_code,
    case item when 'cc' then cnt else '' end as cc_qty,
    case item when 'cc' then code else '' end as cc_code,

    case item when 'pfr' then cnt else '' end as pfr_qty,
    case item when 'pfr' then code else '' end as pfr_code,
    case item when 'bog' then cnt else '' end as bog_qty,
    case item when 'bog' then code else '' end as bog_code
from
    (
        select no, item, sum(cnt) cnt, group_concat( code ) code
        from
            (
                select
                     no, item, count(no) cnt,
                     if( code='', code, concat( code, '-', count(no) ) ) 'code'
                from item_codes ic
                group by ic.no, ic.item, ic.code
            ) ig group by no, item
    ) grouped_data;
```

You may require some changes based on the data differences and other occurrences like null and empty codes, etc.